# Naming AWS resources

Tags: aws

For S3 bucket names, anyone can query a bucket name (without specifying an account owner) and see if the bucket is misconfigured to allow public access.

Therefore, it arguably makes sense to use a complicated name to add an additional level of security, should the bucket settings ever accidentally be changed to public.

Are there other resources in AWS where a similar level of caution could be applied to naming? (i.e. where anyone could query the resource's settings with just the resource name)

Comment: Note that using a "complicated name" is a form of "security by obscurity". As for "other resources", then it logically follows that anything with a URL is publicly searchable and would apply to your concern ...

Comment: For RDS, the endpoint is <db name>.<12-alphanum>.<region>.rds.amazonaws.com. If you set the endpoint to public, the database can be accessible from...the internet. Yes, it would difficult for someone to figure it out but, there is still firewall rules etc. I wouldn't recommend using unreadable names, instead, the focus should be on firewall, access level, etc